# C++ operator+ and operator+= overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm implementing my own matrix class in c++ to help me develop my understanding of the language. I read somewhere that if you've got a working += operator, to use it in your + operator. So that's what I've got:

```
template <class T>
const Matrix<T>& Matrix<T>::operator+(const Matrix<T> &R){

    Matrix<T> copy(*this);
    return copy += R;
}
```

And here is the += operator overload:

```
template <class T>
const Matrix<T>& Matrix<T>::operator+=(const Matrix<T> & second_matrix){
    //Learn how to throw errors....
    if (rows != second_matrix.getNumRows() || cols != second_matrix.getNumCols()){throw "Dimension mismatch.";}
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            data[i][j] += second_matrix.get(i,j);
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

I can use the += just fine (eg, a += b; returns no errors). But calling the + operator (eg, a = b + c;) returns :

```
test.cpp.out(77055) malloc: *** error for object 0x300000004: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

Just for completeness, here's my destructor:

```
template <class T>
Matrix<T>::~Matrix(){
    for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++){
        delete[] data[i]; }
    delete[] data;
}
```

I've been using C++ for a couple years on and off, and still have trouble sometimes keeping track of pointers. I hope that's normal...
Any help would be great. Thanks!

EDIT: here's my copy constructor. It was set to free the data arrays but i removed that. now I get segmentation faults.

```
template <class T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(const Matrix<T>& second_matrix){

    rows = second_matrix.getNumRows();
    cols = second_matrix.getNumCols();
    data = new T*[rows];

    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        data[i] = new T[cols];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            data[i][j] = second_matrix.get(i,j);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What's your copy constructor look like?  That's likely your problem, since the error indicates that memory is being freed twice.

Comment: @Walt W: Yeah, I suspect this is a Big Three problem.

Comment: @Fred: what's a big three problem?

Comment: And now that we see you have a valid one of those, see Fritschy's answer :)

Comment: Don't be tricked into the bad habit of thinking to const references as a smart way to pass values around... when doing that you should always think about lifetime and possibly aliasing. In this case you're returning a reference to a local variable and that's a no-no.

Comment: @JakeVA: The Big Three (or [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)) is that if you need to define any of the copy constructor, copy assignment operator, or the destructor, you most likely need to define all three. I think you may have violated that rule.

Comment: @Jake: Fred refers to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29). In your case, make sure that you also have a valid assignment operator (`operator=`), additionally to the copy constructor.

Comment: what if I'm assigning a matrix to a variable already pointing to a matrix? if I don't delete the arrays in the assignment operator, won't i have a memory leak?

Comment: @JakeVA: yes, and that's why the Rule of Tree is usually true. A naive assignment operator won't delete the old arrays, but your custom one should (or it should reuse them, depending on the class)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`operator+()` should not return a reference type as it is a new (locally declared) instance that holds the result of the operation.

Comment: +1: You're returning a reference to an object (the Matrix copy) that is immediately destroyed when the stack is unloaded; C++ references are not the same as Java / C# / etc references.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I have implemented such operators for a **Matrix class**, this is based on a **Vector Class**. Once you define some operators all other should be defined in terms of the simplest operators:

```
Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& rMatrix) :
    _iRows(rMatrix._iRows), _iColumns(rMatrix._iColumns), _pVector(0)
{
    _pVector = new Vector[_iRows];
    for (int i = 0; i < _iRows; i++) { _pVector[i] = rMatrix._pVector[i]; }
}

Matrix& Matrix::operator=(const Matrix& rMatrix)
{
    if (this != &rMatrix)
    {
        if (0 != _pVector) { delete[] _pVector; pVector = 0; }
        _iRows = rMatrix._iRows;
        _iColumns = rMatrix._iColumns;
        _pVector = new Vector[_iRows];
        for (int i = 0; i < _iRows; i++) { _pVector[i] = rMatrix._pVector[i]; }
    }
    return *this;
}
Matrix& Matrix::operator+=(const Matrix& rMatrix)
{
    *this = *this + rMatrix;
    return *this;
}

Matrix Matrix::operator+(const Matrix& rMatrix) const
{
    Matrix matrix(_iRows, _iColumns);
    ValidateSizes(rMatrix);
    for (int i = 0; i < _iRows; i++) { matrix._pVector[i] = _pVector[i] + rMatrix._pVector[i]; }
    return matrix;
}

Matrix operator+(const Matrix& rMatrix, double dNum)
{
    Matrix matrix(rMatrix._iRows, rMatrix._iColumns);
    matrix.ValidateSizes(rMatrix);
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix._iRows; i++) { matrix._pVector[i] = dNum + rMatrix._pVector[i]; }
    return matrix;
}

Matrix operator+(double dNum, const Matrix& rMatrix)
{
    return operator+(rMatrix, dNum);
}

bool Matrix::ValidateSizes(const Matrix& rMatrix) const
{
    if (_iRows != rMatrix._iRows) { /* THROW EXCEPTION */ }
    if (_iColumns != rMatrix._iColumns) { /* THROW EXCEPTION */ }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If this a matrix for 3D rendering/simulation I would recommend NOT dynamically allocating the memory like that. You can end up with the memory being spread all over the place which causes caching issues. It also leads to potential memory bugs.

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
   public:
      T   m_Data[4][4];
};
```

or if you want something non-4x4

```
template <typename T, unsigned int rows, unsigned int columns>
class Matrix
{
   public:
      T   m_Data[rows][columns];
};
```

and then dynamically allocate the Matrix objects.

Comment: This is off-topic, but i've done some 3d work and can see myself wanting to use my matrix class there, and I see what you mean. any links or other advice?